# ASP MVC Access Dropdownlist from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, ado.net

i am creating an `SchoolManagement` Application in which i have to create an `StudentRegistration` form. on form page i have to display the `Dropdownlist` that will also come from database. i am new to asp mvc, it was so easy in asp.net but in MVC i don't know how to do that. i am using `Ado.net` and Razor view engine. Please someone guide which steps are needed for that.
this is my model class

```
 public class StudentModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Student ID is required", AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Student Roll No is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public int RollNo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Student Name is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Student Address is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Student Cell is required", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Cell { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create Action Method, which will fill your dropdown. You need to set the list of `SelectedListItem`.
So, explain you`r using entity framework.

Your method will be something like this.

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var model = new RegistrationViewModel()
    {
       StudentsList = this.context.Students.Select(s => new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = s.Name,
            Value = s.Id.ToString()
         },
    // some other property to the model
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

In the View:

```
//SelectedStudent - string property in your model, where will be stored Value from list

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedStudent, Model.StudentsList)
```

And in POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegistrationViewModel model) 
{
    var studentId = int.Parse(model.SelectedStudent);
}
```